# How did abridged versions of anime get started?

Tags: anime-history

I was watching anime clips on YouTube and I stumbled upon an abridged version of an anime. The process of dubbing an anime using the same scenes but with a different voice and script, they were changing the dialogues of characters to make it funny.

[This is an example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qW4dY7w8Mz0)

It was Gundam Wing (Entitled *"Gundam Abridged-ning"*)

So how did this kind of voice dubbing and making it more funny get started?

Comment: I don't have the source for it, but I believe it all started with Yu-Gi-Oh abridged. I can be wrong though.

Comment: @Frosteeze Would [this fan-dubbing](http://www.seishun.org/2005/03/laputa-ii-sequel.html) (from 1989 or so) count as an abridged series?

Comment: @Maroon I don't think that YGOTAS (inarguably the progenitor of the modern phenomenon of "abridged series") is "genealogically" related to fandubs from way back when, if you get what I mean. YGOTAS probably isn't the first fan work to do the "put funny English voices on anime" thing, but it was definitely the impetus for all the copycats of recent years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[LittleKuriboh's](https://www.youtube.com/user/CardGamesFTW) [Yu-Gi-Oh! Abridged](http://abridgedseries.wikia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_The_Abridged_Series) is often cited as being the first abridged series and the one to start inspiring others in a chain reaction like manner. (The [latest episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wr13DYngSqE) even makes fun of this fact.)

The linked wiki page mentions that he originaly

> ... was inspired variously by the editing process of The Blair Witch Project, and Reduced Shakespeare Company's The Complete Works of Shakespeare (Abridged).

The series is notable in that it was for a long time voice acted and edited by a single person.

Comment: Credit to Console Argonaut for linking the wiki site. That made writing this answer easier.